# Microsoft Azure - Unable to generate the access token using user name and password using ADAL4J library

Tags: adal

I have been using the adl4j library to get the access token using user name and password. It was working on-until few weeks back and now it was broken.

I am getting an error as "client secret / client association " is required. I have also tried with lastest released jar which is 1.2.0 version and having the same error.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
public Future acquireToken(final String resource,
final String clientId, final String username,
final String password, final AuthenticationCallback callback)
```

However, I don't find the method signature to provide the client secret along with user name and password ?

Can you pls help me to fix this issue?

Here is log message :

> com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException:
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException:
>   {"error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the
>   following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.\r\nTrace ID:
>   708fffa5-eaeb-4722-98e1-ce75c9020d00\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   888b629b-136b-43b8-9403-90bd308db815\r\nTimestamp: 2017-04-04
>   22:30:41Z","error":"invalid_client"}

Answer (score 1):

You registered an web app(confidential app) on Azure which requires secret when acquire the token.

If you want to use the **Resource Password Owner Credentials Flow** in this scenario, you can register an **native app**.

Comment: Thanks fei-xue-msft

Comment: @RamMittala Please don't hesitate to let me know if you still have the problem.